# .php in a routes path for Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am migrating a site from a vanilla PHP site to Laravel. Is there a way to include the old URL paths `/products.php?id=1` to match a route in `routes.php`?

I want to be able to redirect them to the correct URL, extract the id variable and restructure the URL to match the new routes.

Comment: Alexey has a great answer, but you can also do this at the webserver level (`.htaccess`, for example, if you're on Apache).

Comment: Depending on the number of URLs that you want to redirect, you might want to look into [Spatie's missing page redirector package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a route with `.php`:

```
Route::get('products.php', 'ProductController@index');
```

And use it:

```
public function index()
{
    $id = request('id');
}
```